# jQuery PHP API - Issue setting up pagination

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this little API that is giving out the database records for 750 beers. I want to limit it by 20 beers and when I press next it will give me the next 20 beer records, sorted by ID.

I setup the MySQL query to limit 0,20 for the first call (when the page is requested). Then I figured when I press the 'next' button, I'd pull the last ID on the page and pass it to the API trough an AJAX request.

Then I wrote a few extra lines in PHP to check if the latest id isn't empty, then it should do id=id+20. Changing the MySQL request to ask for LIMIT 20,20 , but somewhere something is going wrong and I can't seem to find the error I made...

My PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET["biertjes"])) {

$latestId = $_POST['lid'];
if(!$latestId == 0){
    $latestId = $latestId + 20;
}
else {
    $latestId = 0;
}

$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM bier
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 20,20"; 
$run_query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){

$ids = array();
$namen = array();
$brouwerijen = array();
$types = array();
$gistingen = array();
$percs = array();
$inkoop_prijzen = array();
$biertjes = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $naam = $row['naam'];
    $brouwerij = $row['bouwerij'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $gisting = $row['gisting'];
    $perc = $row['perc'];
    $inkoop_prijs = $row['inkoop_prijs'];

    $ids[] = $id;
    $namen[] = $naam;
    $brouwerijen[] = $brouwerij;
    $types[] = $type;
    $gistingen[] = $gisting;
    $percs[] = $perc;
    $inkoop_prijzen[] = $inkoop_prijs;

}   

for($i=0; $i < count($ids); $i++){

    $biertjes[] = array("id"=>$ids[$i], "naam"=>$namen[$i], "brouwerij"=>$brouwerijen[$i], "type"=>$types[$i], "gisting"=>$gistingen[$i], "perc"=>$percs[$i], "inkoop_prijs"=>$inkoop_prijzen[$i]);

}

echo json_encode($biertjes);
}
}
```

my Jquery:

```
    $("body").delegate( "#volgende", "click", function() {

    var row = $("#biertabel");
    var tr = row.find("tr:last");
    var bier = tr.find("td:nth-child(4)"); 

    for (var i = 0; i < biertjes.length; i++) {
        console.log("Dit is biertje:" +biertjes[i].naam);
        console.log("We zoeken naar :" +bier.html());
        if( bier.html() == biertjes[i].naam ) {
            console.log("Het juiste biertje is gevonden! Gegevens inladen...");
            var id = biertjes[i].id;
            console.log("Klaar met laden van gegevens.");
            break;
        }
    }

    $("#biertabel").remove();
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
    url :   "action-api.php",
    async: false,
    method: "GET",
    data: {biertjes:1,lid:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success :   function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
        biertjes = data;

        var html = '<table style="width:100%" id="biertabel"> <tr> <th>Edit</th> <th>Info</th> <th>Delete</th> <th>Naam</th> <th>Percentage</th> </tr>';

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            html+='<tr><td><div class="edit"><img src="img/edit.png"/></div></td>';
            html+='<td><div class="info"><img src="img/info.png"/></div></td>';
            html+='<td><div class="delete"><img src="img/delete.png"/></div></td>';
            html+='<td>'+item.naam+'</td>';
            html+='<td>'+item.perc+'</td></tr>';
        });

        html+='</table>'
        container.append(html).css(tableCss());
        return biertjes;
    },  

});     
return biertjes;


});
```

Comment: Pls share the error message or unexpected behaviour because it is pretty tough to hunt for an unknown issue in such a lengthy piece of code

Comment: I don't see $latestId variable used?

Comment: @Paul Its supposed to be like this: $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM bier
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT $latestId,20";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX call is a GET and you are looking for a POST variable:

```
$latestId = $_POST['lid'];
if(!$latestId == 0){
    $latestId = $latestId + 20;
}
else {
    $latestId = 0;
}
```

try this

```
$latestId = $_GET['lid'];
if(!$latestId == 0){
    $latestId = $latestId + 20;
}
else {
    $latestId = 0;
}
```

Comment: You also need to do some reading up on SQL injection attacks and sanitising your input as some other posters have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want to page through all 750 "beers", you need to use a [parameter for the offset part of the query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm139875185016992). I assume that is what your `$latestId` is for, but I don't see that you've actually used it.

Something like this:

```
$beers = array();

$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM bier
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT ?,20"; 

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $latestId);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $beers);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Its supposed to be like this: $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM bier
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT $latestId,20";

Comment: It's not recommended to inject a value like that, but sure, it would work if you're fine with SQL injection. That's not what you've posted in your question, though.

Answer (score -1):

JQuery Pagination -  You ca n use jquery pagination

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

or

Change to

```
if(!$latestId == 0)
```

from

```
if(!$latestId)
```